# Splitting a htm file into separate lines in python

Tags: python, file, input, split

So I have a .htm file which I need to split into different lines and store in a list.
So the code I used for this was as follows.

```
html = open('filename.htm').read().splitlines()
```

However when I do the following, the entire file is printed out at once and not line by line and so it seems the input from the file is not being split into different lines

```
for line in html:
    print(line)
```

Additionally, when i try to copy paste the contents of the file to the program, it works fine.

```
html = raw_input()
html = html.splitlines()
```

Could anyone tell me how to get the input from the file to be split into different lines? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since `for line in html: print(line)` means print all the lines, it obviously print the entire files, one line at the time.

So, unless you file is "consolidated" on a single line of text, it's working. You can add some text output to ascertain it:

```
html = open('try.htm').read().splitlines()
for line in html:
    print("Line:")
    print(line)
    print()
```

Comment: sorry, perhaps i was not being clear. The program prints all the lines. But it prints them at once and not line by line which is what I want.

Comment: Can you upload your input file somewhere? Maybe that's the problem. Or maybe I misunderstood what you meant by "line by line".

Comment: I am not sure where to upload it...but its is from the page source of this link : http://www.osvdb.org/show/osvdb/93456

Comment: Yes, that is what i would like to have. Could you paste your exact code here?

Comment: Well...weirdly i am still getting my original output...there is no change with your code. The 'Line:' is printed out and then the entire source file at once and then finally the '()' gets printed out. Could I know what version of python your using?

Comment: Python 3.3.0 but it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want the `read()` part in your first call. Try this:

```
htmllines = open('filename.htm').readlines()
for line in html:
    print line
```

If your HTML file is definitely on multiple lines not just one line as Dek suggests, then make sure you have the right encoding for your file - you might need to decode as follows:

```
htmllines = open('filename.htm').read().decode("Some Encoding").splitlines()
for line in html:
    print line
```

Comment: So i tried readlines() but its the same....everything is still printed out at once which indicates the file input is not being split into various lines...btw, what encoding do you suppose i try?

Comment: The most likely encoding to check is 'Windows-1252' or 'Latin-1' but to be honest I'm not sure if that's actually what the problem is.

Try going into the Python debugger and running:
`>> f = open('filename.htm')`

then trying a different `.decode('encoding')` calls to see if you get a nicer output.

Answer (score 0):

what about `file.readlines([sizehint])` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need `readlines()` and not `splitlines()`. And your code goes like below

```
all_lines = open('sample.html').readlines()

for line in all_lines:
    print(line)
```

To store as a list you can do

```
lst = list(open('sample.html').readlines())
```